# Avoid crashing the Handler thread in case of Runtime Exception?

Tags: android, android-handler

I have a Handler(Thread) on which I post Runnables. In case a Runnable by mistake throws a RuntimeException, the whole app process crashes. As a default that sounds sensible, but I would like to catch such runtime exceptions, log an error, and continue running. I have difficulty making that work, though. I thought of the following options:

1. Subclass `Looper` and override `loop()` which contains the code that calls the `run()` method of the posted Runnables. That did not work since `Looper` is final.
2. Subclass `HandlerThread` and override the run method which calls the `Looper.loop()`. In case of a runtime exception, call `super.run()` again and so forth. That did not work since "only one Looper may be created per thread".
3. In each runnable class, include a try-catch for Runtime exceptions. This will work, but is rather annoying since I have rather many different Runnable classes. Also, would not protect the handler thread if a runnable by mistake forgets to include the try-catch.

In a perfect world, Looper would have a member method called `registerExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler)` and the `ExceptionHandler` would then be called in case of an exception.

Anyone got a better suggestion?

Comment: put the code of runnable in try-catch block and catch the exception. So runnable won't throw catched exceptions. You can manage exception in catch block as per your need.

Comment: Right, I think that is what I call option 3 and I see that as a work-around. The problem is I have several Runnable classes, and would like to avoid to add such code to each one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this custom Handler:

```
class H extends Handler {
    public H(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
        // catch any Exception
        try {
            super.dispatchMessage(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "dispatchMessage " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

testing code:

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("hthread");
ht.start();
Handler h = new H(ht.getLooper());

Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException("testing exception");
    }
};
h.post(r);
h.post(r);
```

Comment: Yes, that is how you setup and start a HandlerThread. If you do something like `ht.post(new RuntimeGeneratingRunnable)`, the app process will crash. Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: dont use Runnables, use send*Message* and Handler.Callback

Comment: Right, that would work. I would have to transform into using messages instead of Runnables, so I think I would prefer to add try-catches to all Runnables... If nothing better comes up.

Comment: or, you can use Runnables as well but you need your custom Handler with overriden dispatchMessage method: try { super. etc

Comment: Please update your answer to match the requirements from the question creator. :)

Comment: pskink: I have been looking for a dispatchMessage() equivalent for runnables but I cannot find it... In fact I cannot see any way to affect the way Runnables are being handled. I have also considered subclassing handler, but I cannot see how that would help. Maybe I misunderstand what you are proposing?

Comment: @TommyTh Runnables are dipatched in dispatchMesdage, try my code

Comment: You are absolutely right. Runnables also get routed through `dispatchMessage()`. Some sort of special message pressumably. Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @TommyTh one more note: if you have dozens of Runnables i would suggest overriding handlwMessage for better performance and using Messages since each Runnable is a standalone class that has to be loaded by vm, i saw in official sources that google prefers Messages to Runnables

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world `DefaultExceptionHandler` works like a charm for me throughout application. Where it causes unhandled  Exception it triggers up.

Library named [Android-Remote-StackTrace](https://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/source/browse/src/com/nullwire/trace/DefaultExceptionHandler.java?r=0ef73a0079f5c8d26d377e9a96996fff2f569016).  You just need to register the broadcast of these DefaultHandlerException class in your Application class.

Snippet:

```
 public class Portfolio extends Application {
 static Portfolio portfolio;
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    portfolio = this;
    ExceptionHandler.register(portfolio);// registering for unhandled Exceptions
   }
 }
```

You can do various task with these such as uploading the log stack trace to your server or send mails on the crash of application as a Crash Report with your unhandled Stack Trace.

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for, but certainly seems useful. My immediate thought is that it is too late to "recover" the handler thread, but I am not sure. I will investigate and let you know. Thanks for responding!

Comment: I have looked at it. I was not aware that a DefaultExceptionHandler existed; certainly interesting and worth a read. For this particular case, it would mean that any pending runnables in the queue will be lost and the handler thread would have to be restarted, etc. So not a really good fit, unfortunately:-(.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way seems to be to derive from Runnable:

```
public abstract class RunnableBase implements Runnable
{
    public final void run()
    {
        try {
            runInternal();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // handle the exception
        }
    }

    // to be implemented by concrete subclasses
    protected abstract void runInternal();
}
```